# DataFrame with multidimensional values

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe, multidimensional-array

I want to create a DataFrame that contains not 1-dimensional arrays in one or more columns.
This is the example:

```
array1 = numpy.array([1,2])
array2 = numpy.array([[1,2],[3,4]])

A     B
1    [1, 2]
2    [3, 4]
```

When I try to insert the numpy as `df['A'] = array1` it says that it must be 1-dimensional. 
Initializing it with

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['A', 'B'])
```

it says that it cannot fit (758) in shape (758,3). 
If I try to insert value by value with a for-cycle, when I retrieve the column the shape is not the one I need.
Thank you!

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: My expected output is a dataFrame like the one I wrote, where I can retrieve the array back again as they were stored. In the duplicate, they use xray and for-cycle with standard array, it didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe you need to use a multiindex dataframe instead.